# Time Between Treatment

Tags: repeated-measures

Suppose a treatment (A or B) is administered multiple times. Consider the following table:

```
     Subject   Treatment    Time
       1          A           1
       1          A           3
       1          A           10
       2          B           2
       2          B           5
       2          B           6
       2          B           12
       2          B           20
```

So Subject 1 is administered Treatment A at time 1, etc. Would it make sense to compare the treatments based on the total time? So for example, subject 1 was administered treatment A at time 1 and at time 10 and the time between would be 9 units. Subject 2 was administered treatment B at time 5 and time 20 and the time between would be 15 units. Thus treatment A is "better" than treatment B because it was administered for less total time.

How would you use the fact that the treatments are administered multiple times to compare them?

Answer (score 1):

I think in order to answer that question fully, we would need more information on what is the outcome you are looking at.

Generally, for time course data, it can be useful to look at growth curve analysis models where you are evaluating the outcome as a function of time (and perhaps dosing of treatment, depending on what these data are representing).  Whether a treatment is "better" based on the time between dosing likely depends on the particular treatment as well as the response to treatment.

Comment: I don't have any outcome variables. All I know is that each subject was either treated with drug A or drug B and the administration dates of those drugs.

Comment: What is the ultimate question you're trying to answer with those data? And what was the reason for the administration of the drugs (e.g., does drug administration relate to some kind of acute episode?).

Comment: The ultimate question is to examine how treatment time varies by drug for a disease (malaria). I am just trying to see what the best way to do this is.

Comment: If your ultimate question is just to look at total treatment time (so last time point - first time point), I think the best bet would be to create a variable that just looks at total time being treated (last-first) and run a t-test.  It doesn't sound like frequency of treatment doses impacts what you're attempting to evaluate.

Comment: Are you at Drexel?

Comment: yes - why do you ask?

Comment: @lkg_student: just wondering, went there. What is your opinion about orthorexia? Is it a subtype of anorexna nervosa?